# "I reinstalled it and now it works" - close as off-topic: cannot be reproduced, or leave it alone?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, declined-flags

I flagged [PHP Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found after building PHP 5.6 from source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26308878/2359271) as off-topic with the no-repro/typo reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can **no longer be
>   reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**. While similar
>   questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner
>   unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by
>   identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to
>   reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Because the asker has edited this into the beginning of the question:

> Solution:
>
> ```
> the previous php installation was not removed cleanly, I need to do 
> yum remove php-common
> ./configure
> make install
> not it works
> ```

The flag was declined, so I'm looking for some general feedback. It was a bit of a confusing situation; the OP edited that into the question, then edited it out again, at which point I left a comment asking if they had actually solved it or not, and to post an answer if so. But they just edited the solution back into the question.

This seems awfully localized. Should I have grabbed the edit and turned it into a wiki answer instead of flagging the question as no-repro? Something else?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, make sure the question is descriptive enough that someone else encountering the same problem could conceivably *find* it. Doesn't even have to be easy - if you're sufficiently motivated, you'll read an awful lot of similar questions in search of one that matches your weird problem.

Then, suggest the author post his answer as an answer. You can *also* edit it out of the question and create an answer yourself if you wish (CW is polite).

Yes, it's pretty localized. But not necessarily unique to the asker; I'm sure most of us have found ourselves searching the 'Net for similar problems at one point or another... Broken installations are a pain to diagnose.

Comment: The problem now is that the question is closed, so the OP cannot post his answer and the whole question looks a bit confusing.

Comment: Ok, so that's annoying but probably due to the attention *this* question directed at it. [I've fixed up *this* instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308878/php-fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found-after-building-php-5-6-from-source/26386769#26386769), hopefully this will be easier to resolve in the future.

Comment: Excellent! Maybe there could be a special flag in the future for such cases: "convert part of the question into an answer, no matter if the question is closed".

Comment: This is *fairly* rare; if you can't fix it yourself by just editing the question and posting a wiki answer, you can flag for moderator assistance.

Comment: But, if you have a borked installation, would you get the same error message, "Class 'mysqli' not found"? Or would every borked installation produce a unique error based on *how* it was borked, and what you tried to run on it? I don't know enough about PHP to guess, but I have my doubts.

Answer (score 5):

What seems to my eye to be the operative point in this case is that it's not just as simple as "well, I uninstalled and reinstalled it and it works again" - they did at least note that it was something caused by an unclean uninstallation. While it may not be a terribly global situation, they do provide in a general sense the conditions which would cause the issue to be reproduced for someone else. It may only pass a very low bar in terms of qualifying it as a good question, but I think that would be the argument for why it's not fully a no-repro situation.